# How to create lambda chain in extensions

Tags: c#, lambda

How to create Lambda extensions chains like this in C#?

`someVar.GetOwnProperites().With.DefaultValues.From(datasource);`

I saw this syntax in DI like Automapper I think. But I'm not sure how to do it..

Comment: Couldn't you just look at their source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an extension method which returns the same object

e.g

```
public static class Extensions{
   public static WhateverYouWantToOperateOn With(this WhateverYouWantToOperateOn source){
   //your logic 
   return source;      
}
}
```

For things like With and DefaultValues, there would be a property in the class which returns the instance of the same class.

Comment: `With` is property in initial code, not a method.

Comment: Second part mentions the same, it would be something like this public MyClass With {return {//do some logic; return this;}